# Pasting into Vista console windows broke, why?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, console, clipboard, paste

I use Windows Vista x64 and regularly use command line windows, for instance CMD.EXE. I have enabled QuickEdit Mode (and Insert Mode and AutoComplete), to be able to quickly copy and paste text from and to console windows.

Copying (select block, <kbd>Enter</kbd>) works fine. Pasting (right click) text also works, as long as it has been copied inside a console window. When I copied the text somewhere else however (in an editor, browser or whatever, or using CLIP.EXE), pasting into a console window does *not* work! :-(

This applies to all kinds of console windows: CMD.EXE, Cygwin bash.

Using the menu to **Edit**, **Paste** does not do anything either, so it's not a mouse thing. I also tried elevating CMD.EXE. I *can* copy/paste freely *between* console windows of all sorts: cmd/bash, elevated/normal, x64/x86...

I'm sure it *did* work on this machine until relatively recently. What could have happened? Some Windows Update perhaps?

The problem has been [reported](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/208198-text-paste-not-working-command-window.html) by [others](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/90704-cannot-paste-command-line.html), but without a solution.

Comment: I don't have any problems with elevated/LUA copy and pasting.  You don't happen to have any clipboard managers running?

Comment: @surfasb No, except for rdpclip.exe.

Comment: So I assume you are using an RDP connection into a Terminal Server?

Comment: @surfasb I use Remote Desktop to the machine regularly. But the pasting (also) fails when I'm directly at the keyboard.

Comment: It sounds so strange, because in Vista, third party programs can no longer stall the message queue as the OS now handles the clipboard msg queue.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>e</kbd> > <kbd>p</kbd> - works in any mode, and, after you get used to it, is almost as fast as any other shortcut.

Comment: For me it doesn't ("Using the menu to Edit, Paste does not do anything either"), that's why I asked...